# Boundedness of a function.

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking at the function $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ over the open interval $(0,\infty)$. It is clear that this function tends to $e$ as $x\to\infty$. I have managed to prove the following:

1. The function is monotone increasing over the said interval.
2. The limit of $f(x)$ at infinity is equal to $e$.

However, I have troubles with a technicality: To show the limit at infinity exists, I first have to show that $f(x)$ has an upper bound over the said interval (In fact I think it would be better if I can show $f(x)$ has a supremum, which is $e$). Then, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem(MCT) I can then claim that since $f(x)$ is monotone increasing and is bounded above by a supremum, thus, it will converge to its supremum.

Would this, in fact, be possible? Or is there other alternatives to rigorously prove that the limit at infinity exists for this function?

Comment: Note, that an upper bound suffices for the monotone convergence theorem as by the completeness of the real numbers, every subset $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ which is bounded above has a supremum. To actually show that the limit is $e$, it would of course be more convenient to show that the supremum is $e$.

Comment: $e$ is often defined as the limit of that function, or at least as the limit over the natural numbers. So, once you prove that the limit exists it must be $e$. If you have a different definition of $e$ then you will need to specify which of the many other equivalent definitions must be reached. That is bounded by $3$ can be proved by induction and so can be proven that it is increasing.

Comment: @blub how does one show that the supremum is actually e? Or how do I even show that f(x) has an upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} = \exp \left( x \ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$

Now note that 
$$ x \ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) \sim x \times \frac{1}{x} =1$$

So 
$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}  \rightarrow \exp(1) =e$$